# Heroes of might and Magic 6: First base not making recruits?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I'm playing through the first campaign and I have captured two fortifications so far, but my initial fortress is not producing and recruits. I have upgraded it many times, but every week there is nothing produced (the captured fortresses are producing fine). Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Can't remember the first mission all too well, but are there any dwellings built in that fortress? You need to have the appropriate building for a particular unit for that unit to spawn at the start of the week.

Comment: Are you recruiting everything from one town, then looking for units in other towns? If so you'll never find any.  6 has a shared unit pool, so every town contributes X units to the pool, they are all recruitable from any town with that dewlling type.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. How does this affect the pool if one town has upgraded units though? Will they show as non-upgraded in the other towns  and only the unit is represented, not the tier? Also, please submit an answer.